# Understanding the limitations of the bignumber.js library

Tags: javascript, bignum, bignumber.js

I have recently found the `bignumber.js` library:

*source:* https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js

What I'm not sure of is if there is a limit to how big the number operations can be? I have been looking into the documentation, trying to find sources online. But nothing as of yet.

Comment: Why not ask on the repo? It's not uncommon to open an issue for clarification or just contact the maintainer directly. That said, (without actually looking) I'd guess it probably stores the numbers as strings giving you an absurdly large max value (for a given base, `b^maxint` I think).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with `bignumber.js` but a small peek into
http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#range has shown me that it seems to be configurable.

```
BigNumber.config({ RANGE: 500 })
BigNumber.config().RANGE     // [ -500, 500 ]
new BigNumber('9.999e499')   // '9.999e+499'
new BigNumber('1e500')       // 'Infinity'
new BigNumber('1e-499')      // '1e-499'
new BigNumber('1e-500')      // '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this:

```
console.log(new BigNumber('123456789012345678901234567890').c);
```

You can see that numbers are stored as arrays, of maximum 14 digits

So the actual limitation would be the maximum length you can have for an array, multiplied by 14. This depends a lot on your machine, but assuming you have the best machine ever, [ECMA-262 v6.0](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) says [the limit is for the length of an array is `2^32-1`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len), which is the size of [ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint32), so, theoretically, you could store a number with `14 * (2^32-1)` digits using that library, that's something like:

```
console.log(new BigNumber(2).pow(32).sub(1).mul(14).toString());
```

Which is something around `60129542130` digits